# Sites with copypasta from MSE?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

Recently, when I surfed the web, I stumbled onto [this](https://www.oipapio.com/question-11012092) and had a deja vu. Despite I see that site for the first time, the answer there was indeed written by me. It's original can still be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188889/407165). While looking at that site further I found that it also contains a lot of other copypasta from MSE. It left me wondering, what purpose do such sites with copypasta serve. Everything that can be found there can be found on the original MSE with less effort, thus making such sites as the aforementioned one somewhat redundant. However, their mere existence indicates, that there is some demand for them. What purpose do such sites serve?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do

Comment: Most likely they serve the purpose of the owner of the site, who presumably profits from the sale of advertising space.

Comment: I think it’s kinda funny how they didn’t even take the effort to parse MathJax/LaTeX.

Comment: This comes up a lot; search for "mirror" on meta. (I wish that we had actual good mirrors, rather than SEO-focused useless crap.)